# Select random item from JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object formatted like this:

```js
Object { 111111={...}, 222222={...}, 333333={...} }
```

The object is called entities. I need to get a random item from this object, such as "111111" or "222222".

Here is my code now:

```js
 var tmpList = Object.keys(entities);
 var randomPropertyName = tmpList[ Math.floor(Math.random()*tmpList.length)];
 var propertyValue = entities[randomPropertyName];
```

This sets propertyValue to "[object Object]". I want it to be "111111", or "222222", or "333333" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is exactly correct.

`randomPropertyName` is returning you one of the keys from the `entities` object and then you are using that key as a reference to return whatever value is assigned to it in `entities` (using `entities[randomPropertyName]`).

At the beginning of your question, though, you describe the value of each of your keys as objects (`{...}`), so that is what `propertyValue` has assigned to it . . . an object.

If you want the key (e.g., "111111", "222222", etc.), then you would reference `randomPropertName` instead of `propertyValue`. . . if you want some additional data from within value stored in `propertyValue`, then you will have to reference it specifically by it's key like this: `propertyValue.KEY_NAME` or this: `propertyValue[KEY_NAME]`.